# How to Remove Items from Excluded Changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, team-explorer

I added some files to my Solution and then deleted after some code tests. Now, the items are still in Excluded Changes of Team Explorer. How can I refresh Visual Studio Excluded Changes panel so that the removed items go away?

Comment: Did you try an undo?

Comment: @derape, No I didn't. Could you please explain what undo means here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your version of Visual Studio you will have a pending changes window (probably under the `Team Explorer` tab). Just select the deleted file, open the context menu and select `Undo...`

For more information also have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245456(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am confirming the Undo under the "Excluded Changes" section merely removes the tracking, it is not Undo in the sense or a re-include or re "[add]" the deleted file.  I'm only commenting because the documentation link really did not clarify the potential equivocation of the meaning of Undo for the deleted file and excluded changes scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Open excluded changes, do not promote but right-click -> select all -> delete from disk

Comment: If you don't want to delete all of them you can select a group by clicking on one and then shift clicking another. Then right-click and delete.  (Also, you can't delete them if anyone of them has the 'add' action.)

Answer (score 4):

Select the file(s) from the 'Team Explorer' tab, Under the 'Excluded Changes'
Open context menu on any of those files, and click on 'Open is Source Control Explorer', and there you could open the context menu again on those files and select 'Undo Pending Changes'

Answer (score 1):

Just right-click the pending change in Team Explorer, select "open in Source Control Explorer", find the item, then right-click to delete.